# What is this type of table called?

Tags: relational-database, database

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM 
(
  SELECT a, b, c 
  FROM ABC 
  WHERE f = '1'
LEFT JOIN 
  SELECT v, n, m
  FROM VBN
  WHERE g = '1'
ON (v = a)
);
```

I am trying to select from a table is is built on the fly from conditions, what is this kind of table called? Live table?

Comment: what do you mean about built on the fly? do you mean subquery?

Comment: yes selecting from the subquery, is there any name i can apply to such table?

Answer (score 0):

You can call it as subquery.
If you wanted to apply a name to this subquery you can use an alias or by creating a view.

```
SELECT 
aJoinedTable.* 
FROM 
(
  SELECT a, b, c 
  FROM ABC 
  WHERE f = '1'
LEFT JOIN 
  SELECT v, n, m
  FROM VBN
  WHERE g = '1'
ON (v = a)
) as aJoinedTable;
```